# Are fruiting bodies, basidiocarps, heterokaryotic?

Tags: mycology

In that, if we have a mycelium with genetically compatible hyphae, will the fruiting body created by this mycelium be heterokaryotic, or will it just contain one dikaryotic organism's genetic material?